# right-angled triangle problem

Tags: geometry, triangles

If the hypotenuse is $8$ cm, one of the sides is $ x $ cm, and the other side $4$ cm longer, how do I find the two unknown sides?
I started by applying the Pythagorean theorem like this $x^2+(4x)^2=8^2$ but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: The equation is $x^2+(x+4)^2=8^2$

Comment: It is not 4 times but longer by 4 cm. Eugen is right.

Comment: my bad, i got it now thanks

Comment: ok so i used the quadratic formula and i found answers -2+-2$\sqrt{7}$

Comment: Note that the  $-2-2\sqrt{7}$ cannot be the side of a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

The other leg of the right triangle is $ 4 $ cm $\textit{longer}$ (not $ 4 $ times as long) than the first leg with length $ x $ cm. Thus, the other leg would measure $ x + 4 $ cm, and the equation would be
$$ x^{2} + (x + 4)^{2} = 8^2 $$